# Animating span and li elements on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a questionnaire project which has multiple choice questions.

My page contains a single question and few options with radio buttons for the question.

it's more like

```
<span id="question"/>
<ul id="options"/>
```

below this i have next & previous buttons.

the master list of the questions and their multiple options are saved in a json file and the next question is properly loaded using the following script

```
  function displayQuestion(questionId) {

      $('#options').children().remove();
$("#question").html(questionnaire_json[0].questions[questionId].question);

      for (j = 0; j < questionnaire_json[0].questions[questionId].answers.length; j++) {
        $('#options:last-child').append('<li><input type="radio" name="answer1" />' + questionnaire_json[0].questions[questionId].answers[j] + '</li>');
      }
    }
```

All this is working fine, what i am looking for is to animate () the question and options on the next button press. i tried `animate` and `fadeIn` / `fadeOut` without much luck. can someone guide me please.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this out but I believe that you probably need to make the li display: none; by default and then add a line to slide it down after it's been appended. I'm not sure if this will run synchronously. You may need to add a function to add the markup and then run the line to show them once that function is `.done()`

CSS:

```
ul#options li.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function displayQuestion(questionId) {
    $('#options').children().remove();
    $("#question").html(questionnaire_json[0].questions[questionId].question);

    for (j = 0; j < questionnaire_json[0].questions[questionId].answers.length; j++) {
        $('#options:last-child').append(
            '<li class="hidden"><input type="radio" name="answer1" />' +
            questionnaire_json[0].questions[questionId].answers[j] + 
            '</li>'
        );
    }
    $('#options li.hidden').slideDown().removeClass('hidden');
}
```